# Casting string to int in C

Tags: c

I am trying to find out what this casting operation do:

```
char w[12] = {0};
int r;

r = (int)gets(w);
```

When input is for example 156, the value of r is -1073744588, so it is not a simple conversion to integer.

Comment: Do not use `gets`, first of all.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting string to integer C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7021725/converting-string-to-integer-c)

Comment: You're not casting a string, you're casting a pointer. See, eg: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4872923/conversion-of-integer-pointer-to-integer or better would be to consult a C reference.

Comment: In fact, it is "a simple conversion". `gets` returns a memory address (which is a number), and that address is simply converted to an `int` (possibly giving a negative result, because in general this simple conversion doesn't make much sense).

Comment: Not sure why you ask about a code that makes no sense. Wherever you've found this, leave that place alone...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What your code does is cast the return value of `gets`, which is a pointer to the first character of the user input string, into an `int`. In other words, you are putting the address of the string into an integer, `r`. However, the address is so high that it "wraps around" in the integer `r`, yielding the large negative value.

You are most likely trying to convert the user's input into an `int`. This is the code to do so

```
char buf[80];
int res;

if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin))      /* load input into buf */
    if (sscanf(buf, "%d\n", &res) < 1)  /* try to read integer from buf */
        fprintf(stderr, "Bad input\n"); /* input was bad; write error */
```

Notice, you should **never** use `gets` because it has serious security problems. Use `fgets` instead to read a line from the standard input.

Comment: The `\n` is superfluous there.