# Convert char* to int memory address

Tags: c, pointers, type-conversion

I have:

```c
char* mem = (char*) 0xB8000;
```

Then `mem` is passed to a function. Inside the function, I want to get the number `0xB8000` back and compare it to some other integers. How do I convert `mem` back to the original integer?

Comment: `mem` is a pointer having a value `0xB8000`. It is not going anywhere when passed to the function.

Comment: try `printf("address: %p\n", mem);`

Comment: If `sizeof(long long) >= sizeof(char *)` (which is true on all platforms I know of), then you can do `long long ll = (long long)mem;`

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1845482/what-is-uintptr-t-data-type

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Conversion of integer pointer to integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4872923/conversion-of-integer-pointer-to-integer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To convert any pointer to an integer, do the following:

```c
#include <stdint.h>

uintptr_t ptr_to_integer(const void *ptr) {
    return (uintptr_t) ptr;
}
```

Note that the size of [`uintptr_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/integer) might vary between platforms. Also this is an optional part of the C standard, so technically only `uintmax_t` would be absolutely portable.

Comment: It may be worth noting that `uintptr_t` is an optional feature of the ISO C standard, so it may not work on certain compilers.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel you're right. But you would be hard-pressed trying to find a compiler that doesn't provide this type or other optional typedefs like `uint32_t`.

Comment: Advanced concern: "only unsigned long long would be absolutely portable" --> not quite.  1) `uintmax_t` would be a better choice 2)   Both `unsigned long long` and `uintmax_t` are not _specified_ to be wide enough to roundtrip a pointer - yet _practically_  are .  The simply advantage to `uintptr_t` is that if code failed to compile due to its absence, it is certain that other integer types will also fail to faithfully round-trip.

Answer (score 2):

> How do I convert mem back to the original integer?

*Usually* a cast to `(u)intptr_t` will form the original integer.

```
include <stdint.h>

printf("o: %lX\n", 0xB8000LU);
char* mem = (char*) 0xB8000;
printf("mem %p\n", (void *) mem);
uintptr_t i =  (uintptr_t) mem;
printf("i: %jX\n", (uintmax_t) i);
```

**Pitfalls**

Round tripping `(u)intptr_t` to `void *` to `uintptr_t` (or any integer type) is not specified by C to result in the original value.  Even `void *` to `(u)intptr_t` to `void *` is only specified to return an *equavalent* pointer, not necessarily the same pointer bit pattern.

Casting an arbitrary number like `(char*) 0xB8000` to a pointer is not specified to work.

> "the result is implementation-defined, might not be correctly aligned, might not point to an entity of the referenced type, and might be a trap representation" C17dr 6.3.2.3 5

`(u)intptr_t` are *optional* types - though common. A compliant library may not be able to provide the type.

No corresponding print specifier for `(u)intptr_t`.  A reasonable work-around is to to covert to the widest available type and print.

---

> I want to get the number 0xB8000 back and compare it to some other integers.

A better approach could covert the "other integers" to a `char *` and compare pointers.

Best for OP to post the larger code usage to handle the overall goal.

Proceed with caution.